# Integrating the app with Google search results and Chrome

Tags: android, android-intent, google-chrome-app, intentfilter, google-search

The official Wikipedia app somehow does that, in my app I'm using a standard intent-filter to listen for navigation to Wikipedia urls.

Is there a way to integrate with Google search? Are there any APIs available, or is this only available for the chosen ones?

[image]

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my answer that you see?

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html#webpages), you have to add a meta tag to the pages for which you want the search to display a link to an app. For example, the Wikipedia page linked in the search result from your screenshot, has the following link in its source code:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://org.wikipedia/http/en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_17" />
```

I assume that you cannot add a link to your app to search results by other means: The search results also suggest users to install apps they don't have yet. Giving the power to decide which app is suggested to someone other than the owner of a page would obviously be dangerous. Another strong hint is that the documentation does not mention any alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember correctly Google announced in this years Google I/O that an API to achieve this will be available from Android L

The announcement can be found in the [keynote video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wtLJPvx7-ys#t=2025) at 33:45, although it does not say anything about how it will work

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the deep links in the HTML markup of your web pages. You can do this in the  section for each web page by adding a  tag and specifying the deep link as an alternate URI.

**See example for Wikipedia (I looked for page source of content you searched)**

```
<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.24wmf15" />
<link rel="alternate"
  href="android-app://org.wikipedia/http/en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_17" />
<link rel="alternate" 
  type="application/x-wiki" title="Edit this page" href="/w/index.php?  title=Apollo_17&amp;action=edit" />
```

You need to add below code to you webpages:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="alternate"
      href="android-app://com.example.android/example/gizmos" />
...
</head>
<body> ... </body>
```

Now to handle this intent in application and when you search for something and the link gives you an option for opening in wikipedia app as well, if you would like to support for both, then for that you need to modify your android app.

First, you need to add the scheme in your Manifest.

**Here is how WikiPedia app works.**

WikiPedia app adds the scheme, like below in their page view activity.

```
<activity android:name=".page.PageActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data
    android:scheme="http"
    android:host="*.wikipedia.org"
    android:pathPrefix="/wiki/" />
<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="*.wikipedia.org"
    android:pathPrefix="/wiki/" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You need to do same thing for your domain and it will work. If you need to make sure that your application is also shown in deep links Refer [link1](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app)  and [link2](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html#webpages)

Comment: I am not saying, about the wikipedia's server, what I am saying is that let's say you are having a site called www.foo.com and your android application package is com.example.foo, then in your webpages you need to include href="android-app://com.example.foo/ and have the http & https schema in your android manifest. That will open the result in your app always and it will show the app icon as well in chromium. It works and it's simple. I just explained above how Wikipedia works.

Answer (score 0):

This is called **App Indexing** by the way, and Google has ways of setting this up in Android

### **Here is how to specify a [deep link](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app) to your app content:**

1. In your Android manifest file, add one or more **`<intent-filter>`** elements for the activities that should be launchable from Google Search results.
2. Add an **`<action>`** tag that specifies the **`ACTION_VIEW`** intent action.
3. Add a **`<data>`** tag for each data URI format the activity accepts. This is the primary mechanism to declare the format for your deep links.
4. Add a **`<category>`** for both **`BROWSABLE`** and **`DEFAULT`** intent categories.

   - **`BROWSABLE`** is required in order for the intent to be executable from a web browser. Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to your app and only the current web browser will respond to the URL.
   - **`DEFAULT`** is not required if your only interest is providing deep links to your app from Google Search results. However, the **`DEFAULT`** category is required if you want your Android app to respond when users click links from any other web page that points to your web site. The distinction is that the intent used from Google search results includes the identity of your app, so the intent explicitly points to your app as the recipient — other links to your site do not know your app identity, so the **`DEFAULT`** category declares your app can accept an implicit intent.

### Example

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos">
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In this example, your app would respond to deep links such as...

- http://example.com/gizmos?1234
- http://example.com/gizmos/1234
- http://example.com/gizmos/toys/1234
- etc...

**The intent filter's `<data>` element must provide the `android:scheme` attribute, at a minimum.** You can then add additional attributes to further refine the type of URI that the activity accepts.

More information can be found [here...](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app)

Comment: @animaonline What do you think of this? You don't need to have access to Wikipedia's servers! All you need is an app that you have built. All of my answer is code that goes into your app, and that is all. Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

Android introduce app link api integrate native app content in google search result.The document says:

```
Google's web crawling bot (Googlebot), which crawls and indexes web sites for the Google search engine, can also index content in your Android app. By opting in, you can allow Googlebot to crawl the content in the APK through the Google Play Store to index the app content. To indicate which app content you’d like Google to index, simply add link elements either to your existing Sitemap file or in the <head> element of each web page in your site, in the same way as you would for web pages.

The deep links that you share with Google Search must take this URI format:

android-app://<package_name>/<scheme>/<host_path>
The components that make up the URI format are:

package_name. Represents the package name for your APK as listed in the Google Play Developer Console.
scheme. The URI scheme that matches your intent filter.
host_path. Identifies the specific content within your application.
The following sections describe how to add a deep link URI to your Sitemap or web pages.
```

Also importantly,**if the user does not have the app on the phone and you still want the content to be properly formatted in google search results** you need to use meta tags.The docs 
says:

> Meta tags are a great way for webmasters to provide search engines
>   with information about their sites. Meta tags can be used to provide
>   information to all sorts of clients, and each system processes only
>   the meta tags they understand and ignores the rest. Meta tags are
>   added to the  section of your HTML page and generally look like
>   this:

refer-https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en